Configure hashsize of nf_conntrack_xxx on kernel 5.x
In my system running kernel 4.x, it load 3 modules which are nf_conntrack, nf_conntrack_ipv4 and nf_conntrack_ipv6. Only nf_conntrack_ipv4 is modprobe-ed with hashsize param which is greater than default size of hash table.
Do nf_conntrack_ipv4 and nf_conntrack_ipv6 use the same hash table as I only find one hash table in source code of nf_conntrack which is nf_conntrack_hash?
Also when I porting the system to kernel 5.x, the nf_conntrack_ipv4 and nf_conntrack_ipv6 are no longer available and integrated into single module which is nf_conntrack. If nf_conntrack_ipv4 and nf_conntrack_ipv6 use different hashtable on kernel 4.x, is there a way to configure only size of hash table used by conntrack_ipv4 on kernel 5.x?
